# Adding copyright information to a Website

Tags: privacy, copyright-display

I'm working on a website for a client that is a non-profit. The want a Copyright link at the bottom of the site. My question is do they have any legal rights? What kind of info should i put? etc etc.

Is it good enough to basically just add something like "(c) 2010 [My Client]. All rights reserved."?

Additionally for a user agreement and privacy policy can just copy one that fits our site kind like these:

- http://www.reddit.com/help/useragreement
- http://www.reddit.com/help/privacypolicy

Edit: We are based in the USA if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you create is implicitly copyrighted in the US. It is however helpful to place a notice anyway, and to put somewhere that people actually have permission to actually use the site.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I am not a lawyer, and you may want to consult with one.

That disclaimer aside, I think that by putting "(c) 2010 [My Client]. All rights reserved."
on all the web pages, your intent that the content is yours is clear, and you increase your ownership of the content.

It is not going to stop anyone from copying from your site of course. If someone does and you decide to sue, you may or may not win. But you will have a somewhat better case by having the  "(c) 2010 [My Client]. All rights reserved."  on the site.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what country you're in. In many countries, such as the UK, authors hold copyright whether they assert it or not so you don't actually *need* to do anything. It may be different in the US; check with an IP specialist if you're not sure.

That said, it will be fine to throw in a `(c) Whoever` if it keeps the client happy. It's a common practice. It just may not mean much in a legal sense :)

As for the privacy policy, check that you're not breaching the copyright of whoever wrote the policy you want to copy. Don't just copy it; ask them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add the Copyright sign and symbol, that is fine, as the creator of a creative work has the natural claim over his creative work, so no issues on that at all.

But one should apply for copyright registration as that gives greater legal protection in times of infringement i.e. copying of your creative work in the court of law.

You should read this article: [Copyright laws on Software](http://www.legalserviceindia.com/cyber/copyright.htm) for greater understanding.

From the above answers, it is also important to know a copyright registered in any one of the [Bern Convention countries](http://www.legalserviceindia.com/copyright/bern.htm) is valid in all these countries. There are in all 166 signatory countries as of now. You can see if your country is a member of Bern Convention. If so than your copyright registration will be valid in 166 countries.

Best regards
tarun

Answer (score 1):

If they care enough they should consult with their lawyer. They have one, right? As a contractor I wouldn't touch this with a ten foot pole, because if anything ever happens, guess who they'll be after with pitchforks.